# php function same as "include" but don't shows warning

Tags: php

I don't know PHP well but also I don't want to stop error reporting.

Please tell me a function which won't display errors or warnings when the file is not found but otherwise works the same as the include function, e.g.

```
<?php include("file.txt"); ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php - http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: There's no such function. Over.

Comment: that's a big 10-4 ^ over

Comment: use fopen() and read the file http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add @ in the beginning of this function to hide warning e.g.

```
<?php @include("file.txt"); ?>
```

This way you will not see warning for only this line of code.

Comment: thanks your answer works and i also upvoted but no  one can see my votes until i reach 15 points, can i reach there, you can see 1 negative vote for this question by someone ................

Answer (score 0):

This question should be solved in a way that makes sense, instead of suppressing errors and warnings.

A better way of doing this would be something like:

```
$include_file = "file.txt";
if( file_exists($include_file) && is_readable($include_file) ) {
    include $include_file;
}
```